# Custom tabbar for android app with animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to make a custom tabbar for my android app like image (tabbar for the same app in iphone)

[image]

and when i pass from tab to other it make an animation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a callback with the [TabHost.onSetTabChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29) method., and trigger the animation from there. However, you should also keep in mind that TabHost is deprecated in Android, and you are trying to port very "iOS-ish" behavior to Android, which may not be very natural for your users.